# Mute For-loop output

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I have this for-loop batch to convert a bunch of text files to PDF. Sometimes there are literally thousands of files, which I do not want the output to fill up the log files.

How can I mute the output of this for-loop batch?  I've tried placing `2>NUL` in a few places, without much success.

```bash
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%F IN (D:\TEMP\FILE*.TXT) DO (
    SET TMPFILE=%%F
    SET NEWFILE=!TMPFILE:~0,-4!.PDF
    C:\EXE\txt2pdf.exe !TMPFILE! !NEWFILE! -PFS9
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `@echo off` at the beginning of your batch file?

Comment: Thanks Jeb, unfortunately i have a few other commands above and below this i like to have echo on for.  One way i thought of was to put this particular section in a batch of its own and call it.  I will elect for this route if no better solution.

Comment: You can also completely remove ```SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION```, ```SET TMPFILE=%%F```, and ```SET NEWFILE=!TMPFILE:~0,-4!.PDF```, then change ```C:\EXE\txt2pdf.exe !TMPFILE! !NEWFILE! -PFS9``` to ```"C:\EXE\txt2pdf.exe" "%%F" "%%~dpnF.PDF" -PFS9```. Essentially your entire batch file, _(or single line if you have others)_, could look like this: ```@FOR %%G IN ("D:\TEMP\FILE*.TXT") DO @"C:\EXE\txt2pdf.exe" "%%G" "%%~dpnG.PDF" -PFS9 1>NUL 2>&1```

Comment: Anyone know how do i promote Compo's comment as the answer?

Comment: Well, you could place `@echo off` before this block and `@echo on` behind, for instance. *N. B.:* You cannot promote Compo's comment as an answer, because it is just a comment but not an answer post; as soon as Compo posts an answer, you can upvote and/or accept it…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent output of individual lines you can both turn echoing off individually for the line, using `@`, and prevent both stdOut and stdIn using command redirection `1>` and `2>`.

You can also completely remove `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, `SET TMPFILE=%%F`, and `SET NEWFILE=!TMPFILE:~0,-4!.PDF`, then change `C:\EXE\txt2pdf.exe !TMPFILE! !NEWFILE! -PFS9` to `"C:\EXE\txt2pdf.exe" "%%F" "%%~dpnF.PDF" -PFS9`.

Essentially your entire batch file, (or single line if you have others), could look like this:

```bash
@For %%G In ("D:\TEMP\FILE*.TXT") Do @"C:\EXE\txt2pdf.exe" "%%G" "%%~dpnG.pdf" -PFS9 1>NUL 2>&1
```